# Appium IOS native app application switch

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I click on link in myApplication which redirects me to safari, Now I want to close safari and open back myApplication at same state? Home Button is not supported with appium.

Tried,

1.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(5);
```

But it is closing and opening Safari app again. How can I switch to myApplication instead of safari?

2.
Appium default methods doesn't seem to be working working IOS,

```
driver.closeApp();
driver.launchApp();
```

Quitting driver.

3.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object result = js.executeScript("mobile: closeApp");
HashMap<String, String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();
args.put("bundleId", "com.myApplication.iphone");
js.executeScript("mobile: launchApp", args);
```

Got "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented" error.

4.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] args = {"osascript", "-e", "tell app \"safari\" to quit"};
runtime.exec(args);


runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmd = { "osascript", "-e", "tell app \"myApplication\" to launch" };
runtime.exec(cmd);
```

Not Working.

5.

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        // Simulate a key press
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);

        // Simulate a key press
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Not working

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can see is to set your desired capabilities to not reset the app between sessions `caps.setCapability("noReset", true)`.

Then, after you click the link on Safari and do whatever else you need to do, close the session `driver.quit()` and start a new session using your app again. It should start from where you left off.

Comment: Thank you I see it is redirecting as expected, but Starting a new session using app again is opening app's home page and not the app screen where I left.